# What's getting placed in the initialization stage of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, initialization, interpreter

I'm reading about *function declarations* and *function expressions*. It say's that *function declarations* get placed in the *initialization stage* of JavaScript. Later I found out that *variables* also get placed in there, but they get the value of undefined, and when the interpreter reaches that *variable* it will then be assigned.

I can't find a good article about it. **Now I'm wondering what else gets in the initialization stage of JavaScript?**

Comment: function parameters are also processed as a part of the first pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try searching for javascript **hoisting** ([W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)).

It basically means, no matter where you declare a function or a variable, when the code is run the functions and variables are hoisted to the top and declared.  This is why you can declare functions after you've used them and they still run fine.

However, *initializing* them is different.  From W3Schools

> JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations.

This means that the variables only get their assigned value when they reach the relevant line; functions are the same.

If you use a function expression such as:

```
var foo = function() {
  // your code
}
```

In this case only the variable name will be hoisted and given the value `undefined`, and then if the function gets called **above** the function expression it *will* error as it has not have been assigned the function at this point in the code.